# Is it possible to create Blade directives which behave differently for different users?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I wanted to use Blade directives like

```
@admin
  // template for admin
  @include('layouts.admin')
@endadmin

@notadmin
  // template for usual user
  @include('layouts.meremortal')
@endnotadmin
```

and registered these directives in `AppServiceProvider.php` in `boot()` method.

But after logout of admin and logging in as usual user I continue to see admin part of template(and dont see not admin part).

After switching to

```
@if (Auth::user()->is_admin)

    @include('layouts.admin')

@else 

    @include('layouts.meremortal')

@endif
```

everything seems to work fine.

So the question is: is it possible in general to make Blade directives dynamical or they are transformed to plain PHP only once and don't change during runtime? And if it's possible, then what am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom directives in the boot function of the `AppServiceProvider.php` file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('hello', function ($expression) {
            return "<?php echo 'Hello ' . {$expression}; ?>";
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

For more details you can visit [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-about-writing-custom-blade-directives) reference.

Comment: well yes, this is just what i've written in my question. But the question is why directive doesn't change the state during runtime, i switch users but get the same functional. And I considered the link you gave before asking the question, used code snippets from there)